# Adjective for something that can continue to grow versus being terminal

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a single word that can describe something that is continuing to grow.  The only term that comes to mind is viral but I am looking for something different.

For an example, an activity that continually spawns other activities.

> The smaller tasks continue to grow because of the ______ task.

Comment: I was going to post _viable_, but your question is a little unclear (no sample sentence as required for the SWR tag).

Comment: Please give a sample sentence.

Comment: Sorry I will add a sentence.  For example:  The smaller tasks continue to grow because of the ______  task.

Comment: "Burgeoning" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest **hydralike**, which is an adjective form of 'hydra'.

A Hydra, according to Greek mythology, is a many-headed beast that has a curious habit of growing two more heads every time you cut one off. (Heracles/Hercules had to defeat one in his second task.)

It has taken on the meaning of:

> A complex, multifarious problem or situation that cannot be solved easily and rapidly

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hydra)

And is apt for describing problems that get increasingly complex.

Answer (score 0):

[vigorous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vigorous)
adjective

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vigorous):

2 : possessing vigor : full of physical or mental strength or active force : STRONG
a vigorous youth
a vigorous plant

Answer (score 0):

> [***fecund***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fecund) - producing many good new things

Typically used in the context of fertility or intellectual creativity, per [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fecund)

I'm thinking it's a close synonym to *virulent* with more neutral connotation.

Answer (score 0):

**Spawn**. verb, meaning ‘to produce young ones’

Means ‘continues to birth more young ones, similar to itself’

Consider being poetic and liken it to yoghurt or yeast, baby fish, or... mushrooms.

Each mushroom spawns another fairy ring. Which then spawns others.

The tasks continue to spawn.

INTRANSITIVE/TRANSITIVE] to produce spawn
 Synonyms and related words
Give birth to a young animal:albumen, calve, foal...
Explore Thesaurus
2 [TRANSITIVE] if one thing spawns something else, it creates it
The book was a fantastic success, spawning a hit TV series.
 Synonyms and related words
To make something start to exist or happen:bring about, trigger, form...

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/spawn_2

The tasks continue to spawn further tasks.

Answer (score 0):

[Generative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/generative) seems to be appropriate here.  Something which is generative has the power to reproduce, or produce new things, which I think is what you are looking for.

According to Cambridge Dictionary:
Adjective
able to produce or create something

Example use in phrase:
the generative power of the mind

and the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generative) definition:
 having the power or function of generating, originating, producing, or reproducing

Answer (score -1):

I would say ***SWELLING***.

According to Oxford Living Dictionary

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/:

***SWELLING***

ADJECTIVE

Becoming greater in intensity, number, amount, or volume.

‘the swelling ranks of Irish singer-songwriters’